# Radio buttons, each when clicked displays two buttons, on and off

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, radio-button

I have a set of sixteen radio buttons. When i press a radio button, i want two buttons to appear (on/off). and when i press any button, a function executes(i have no problem with this),;
when i go to the next random radio button and press it,  the same thing should happen., but when i go back to the previous radio button that i pressed, it should still show the action that was carried out(i.e either on/off). It should retain the action carried out on it forever, until manually changed.\
all i need is the demonstration of the above in code for at least 3 buttons, and i will figure out the rest myself....

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify this a little?  A drawing would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger in the XAML, it is fairly simple..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx

So basically you would use the checkbox value of the original to either show or hide (the property in the style to modify) the others.

If XAML is not your cup of tea and you wish to use codebehind (really personal choice) this may help you.. I am not a WPF/MVVM stickler by any means (some duct tape helps now and then) but putting all sorts of events like this in the codebehind can get messy..

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF

Comment: What if i want to do this all dynamically. then xaml won't help me right?, if, during runtime, i want to populate a listview with said radio buttons and only after that is done, i want them to carry out said actions. . . . .then how do i do it?

Comment: You'd have to programmatically attach behavior or data-template them with behaviors already set in the template.

Answer (score -2):

This should be a relatively simple javascript item you need to do. Ensuring that you have ids for each of the items then make all the changes on the page and then on the final postback you will have all the correct values

Comment: c# surely was just saying he works in c# and admit I missed the 'tag' that says wpf but there was no mention of wpf in the actual question